# How can I level a concrete floor in a basement room?

Tags: concrete, flooring, tile, self-leveling-concrete, mudding

I have a room in the basement with a concrete floor that slopes 2" over 11 feet.  It's finished in that it has drywall, but there is no flooring yet.  I need to raise the floor to be level.  The room has a high corner.

**Plan:**

Use dry pack mud to raise the floor to level.  Use thinset on the floor prior to the deck mud to help it adhere.

**Issues/Questions:**

- It's my understanding mud shouldn't touch drywall, so should I cut out the 2" of drywall where I need to level it?
- If I should cut out the drywall, should I put backer board in it's place? (2" of concrete would be over the footer 2x4.
- How thin can I go with deck mud?  I've read the thinnest I can go is 3/4 of an inch.  If that's true, what should I use to finish the last 3/4 of an inch where it feathers into the high corner?

Thank you for your help, any info or links will be appreciated.

Comment: Dry-pack isn't a floor. It's much too soft and porous. What do you plan on installing?

Comment: How big is the room?  Leveling compound might work, but for large areas, it can be expensive.

Comment: @isherwood, thanks for the tip.  It's going to be a gym room, so at this point, it would just be concrete. Not sure what I could put down on the floor below grade that wouldn't mold when ready to sell, but God willing, no plans to sell right now. I'm good working on concrete for the gym floor.  May add tile or waterproof laminate when ready to sell.

Comment: @ChrisM.  It's 11'9" by 11'2".  I was trying to save as much as possible, possibly using cement until I would need to feather, and then maybe use leveling compound.  I'm not sure how to calculate how many bags I would need.

Comment: So go from 3/4" to 2 3/4" on your slope.

Comment: If we call it 12x11, with a 2" drop, you'll need around 30 bags of the 555 leveler we sold at Orange Big Box.  Between the expense and the difficulty using leveler in large areas like that (it sets kind of quickly), I'd say that's a no-go.